# What is going wrong with my DFT program?

Tags: dft

Please let me ask your help on my problem. My following DFT program outputs:

- [Testing frequency's amplitude: $56.9708$, and its phase: $1.32018 \pi \textrm{ rad}.$]

Testing frequency's amplitude should be $57$, then it is okay. But its phase should be $-0.68\pi\textrm{ rad}$. Obviously it is obtained by subtracting: $1.32018\pi\textrm{ rad} - 2\pi\textrm{ rad}$.

But why this?

```
// Testing program for DFT. I change sampling frequency (samplFreq), samples (N)
// testing frequency (testFreq), and two existing in signal frequencies (existFreq_#)
// with their amplitudes (ampl_#) and phases (phase_#). After variable's declaration
// there is, in comment, its unit.

#include <iostream> 
#include "math.h"

int main()
{
   double pi = 3.141592653589793; //pure number.
   int n = 0; // sample.
   double xn = 0; //pure number.
   double Re = 0; //pure number.
   double Im = 0; //pure number.
   double xn_cos = 0; //pure number.
   double xn_sin = 0; //pure number.

   int samplFreq = 3021; // sample/second.
   int N = 4400; //sample.

   double ampl_1 = 57; //pure number.
   double existFreq_1 = 536 * 2 * pi; // 2 * pi rad (cycle)/sec (multiple unit), basic unit: rad/sec.
   double phase_1 = -0.68 * pi; //pirad = pi rad (multiple unit), basic unit: rad.
   double unitAngle_1 = existFreq_1 / samplFreq; // cycle/sample (multiple unit), basic unit: rad/sample.

   double ampl_2 = 91; // pure number.
   double existFreq_2 = 896 * 2 * pi; // 2 * pi rad (cycle)/sec (multiple unit), basic unit: rad/sec.
   double phase_2 = -0.51 * pi; //pirad = pi*rad (multiple unit), basic unit: rad.
   double unitAngle_2 = existFreq_2 / samplFreq; // angle/sample.

   double testFreq = 536 * 2 * pi; // 2 * pi rad/sec (multiple unit), basic unit: rad/sec.
   double testUnitAngle = testFreq / samplFreq; // cycle/sample (multiple unit), basic unit: rad/sample.    

   for (n = 1; n<= N; ++n)
   {
       xn = ampl_1 * sin(n * unitAngle_1 + phase_1)
          + ampl_2 * sin(n * unitAngle_2 + phase_2);

       xn_cos = xn *  cos(n * testUnitAngle);
       xn_sin = xn * -sin(n * testUnitAngle);

       Re += xn_cos;
       Im += xn_sin;
   }  
   double testAmpl = sqrt(Re * Re + Im * Im) / N * 2; //pure number.       
   std::cout << "Testing frequency's amplitude: " << testAmpl;
   std::cout << ", and its phase: " << atan2 (Im, Re) / pi + 0.5 << " pirad." << std::endl; // rad.
return 0;
}
```

Comment: why the 0.5 is added in the final phase computation?

Comment: according to your data, your result was right because there is only difference of one period.

Comment: Since sine and cosine are $2\pi$-periodic, the phase is only determined up to multiples of $2\pi$. A phase value of $\phi$ is equivalent to another value $\phi+2k\pi$, where $k$ is an arbitrary integer. One convention is to choose the phase inside the interval $[-\pi,\pi)$, and this can always be achieved by adding or subtracting multiples of $2\pi$.

Comment: @ Mr. lxg, in my dear dsp Teacher's book "Understanding DSP"? section 3.1, example 3.1.1, every phase is 90° greater than computed. For this, I added 0.5 π rad.

Comment: @ Messrs lxg and Matt L., please let me one more question: Do I have add in program "if" statement that, if computed phase is greater than 1 π rad, 2 π rad be subtracted? Regards.